# Prisma Deploy Docker error "Could not connect to server"

Tags: docker, graphql, prisma

This is steps I have done

```
prisma init
```

I set postgresql for database in my local(not exist).

It created 3 files, datamodel.graphql, docker-compose.yml, prisma.yml

```
docker-compose up -d
```

I confirmed it running successfully 
[image]
But if I call `prisma deploy`, it shows me error

```
Could not connect to server at http://localhost:4466. Please check if your server is running.
```

All I have done is standard operation described in manual and there is no customization in
https://www.prisma.io/docs/tutorials/deploy-prisma-servers/local-(docker)-meemaesh3k

And this is docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  prisma:
    image: prismagraphql/prisma:1.11
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "4466:4466"
    environment:
      PRISMA_CONFIG: |
        port: 4466
        # uncomment the next line and provide the env var PRISMA_MANAGEMENT_API_SECRET=my-secret to activate cluster security
        # managementApiSecret: my-secret
        databases:
          default:
            connector: postgres
            host: localhost
            port: '5432'
            database: databasename
            schema: public
            user: postgres
            password: root
            migrations: true
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation mentions](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/prisma-servers-and-dbs/prisma-servers/docker-aira9zama5/):

> ```
> docker ps
> ```
>
> You should see output similar to this:
>
> ```
> $ docker ps
> CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
> 2b799c529e73        prismagraphql/prisma:1.7            "/bin/sh -c /app/sta…"   17 hours ago        Up 7 hours          0.0.0.0:4466->4466/tcp   myapp_prisma_1
> 757dfba212f7        mysql:5.7                           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   17 hours ago
> ```

(Here shown with mysql, but valid with postgresql too)

The point is: there should be *two* containers running, not one.

Check `docker-compose logs` to see why the second one (database) did not start.

Comment: Thanks, I am running postgresql in my local, in this case how to set prisma to use hosted server's local database?

Comment: @NomuraNori Considering prisma is isolated in container, I am not sure it would be able to access a service (like postgresql) running on the local host.

Answer (score 9):

I found this solution to the same problem i was facing

```
docker-machine ip default
```

Use this address and replace the "localhost" with the IP with the above command to look something like this in prisma.yml file

```
endpoint: http://1xx.1xx.xx.xxx:4466
```

The answer is referred from this [Github Link](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/2675#issuecomment-400326500)

Comment: I get this output: "Docker machine "default" does not exist. Use "docker-machine ls" to list machines. Use "docker-machine create" to add a new one." How to create a docker-machine?

Comment: @kwoxer try this command: `docker-machine create default`. You can read more here: https://docs.docker.com/machine/get-started/

Comment: I'm now using mongo as docker service. So my issue is now gone.

Comment: Said process worked for me. The only difference was I had to run `docker-machine ls` to get the ip.

Answer (score 1):

instead of **docker-compose up -d**
USE:

```
docker-compose up
```

and keep the window running which will keep localhost:4466 alive.

**Note** : If u want to connect to connect to the database created in docker, you need to map the port in the following way:

```
docker run --name <ENTER_NAME> -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=<ENTER_PASSWORD> -d -p 5433:5432 postgres
```

In the above case PORT(5433) = HOST_PORT  and  PORT(5432) = CONTAINER_PORT