# Prisma-docker could not connect to server

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, graphql, prisma

I tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53788462/10567693) but I get an empty list with ls

**Problem:** I can't connect prisma to an atlas free tier cluster

This occurred two times already while setting up graphql server with graphql-yoga and also with apollo-server, so I tried it this time with no server but only prisma.

**My steps:**

in atlas I used load sample data

```
prisma init
```

I chose connect to an existing mongodb and I supplied the connection string (the generated files are in the end of the question)

```
docker-compose up -d
```

the container was created (there was no error here)

```
prisma deploy
```

I got this message:

> Could not connect to server at http://localhost:4466. Please check if your server is running.

So I went and got the container logs

```
docker logs <id>

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load Prisma config: com.prisma.config.InvalidConfiguration: Expected host to be non-empty
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:26)
        at com.prisma.config.ConfigLoader$.load(ConfigLoader.scala:40)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalDependencies.<init>(PrismaLocalDependencies.scala:48)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain$.delayedEndpoint$com$prisma$local$PrismaLocalMain$1(PrismaLocalMain.scala:13)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain$delayedInit$body.apply(PrismaLocalMain.scala:8)
        at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
        at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:34)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
        at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:76)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:388)
        at scala.App.main(App.scala:76)
        at scala.App.main$(App.scala:74)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain$.main(PrismaLocalMain.scala:8)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain.main(PrismaLocalMain.scala) Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load Prisma config: com.prisma.config.InvalidConfiguration: Expected host to be non-empty
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:26)
        at com.prisma.config.ConfigLoader$.load(ConfigLoader.scala:40)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalDependencies.<init>(PrismaLocalDependencies.scala:48)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain$.delayedEndpoint$com$prisma$local$PrismaLocalMain$1(PrismaLocalMain.scala:13)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain$delayedInit$body.apply(PrismaLocalMain.scala:8)
        at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
        at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:34)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
        at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:76)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:388)
        at scala.App.main(App.scala:76)
        at scala.App.main$(App.scala:74)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain$.main(PrismaLocalMain.scala:8)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain.main(PrismaLocalMain.scala) Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load Prisma config: com.prisma.config.InvalidConfiguration: Expected host to be non-empty
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:26)
        at com.prisma.config.ConfigLoader$.load(ConfigLoader.scala:40)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalDependencies.<init>(PrismaLocalDependencies.scala:48)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain$.delayedEndpoint$com$prisma$local$PrismaLocalMain$1(PrismaLocalMain.scala:13)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain$delayedInit$body.apply(PrismaLocalMain.scala:8)
        at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
        at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:34)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
        at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:76)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:388)
        at scala.App.main(App.scala:76)
        at scala.App.main$(App.scala:74)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain$.main(PrismaLocalMain.scala:8)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain.main(PrismaLocalMain.scala) Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load Prisma config: com.prisma.config.InvalidConfiguration: Expected host to be non-empty
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:26)
        at com.prisma.config.ConfigLoader$.load(ConfigLoader.scala:40)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalDependencies.<init>(PrismaLocalDependencies.scala:48)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain$.delayedEndpoint$com$prisma$local$PrismaLocalMain$1(PrismaLocalMain.scala:13)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain$delayedInit$body.apply(PrismaLocalMain.scala:8)
        at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
        at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:34)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
        at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:76)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:388)
        at scala.App.main(App.scala:76)
        at scala.App.main$(App.scala:74)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain$.main(PrismaLocalMain.scala:8)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain.main(PrismaLocalMain.scala) Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load Prisma config: com.prisma.config.InvalidConfiguration: Expected host to be non-empty
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:26)
        at com.prisma.config.ConfigLoader$.load(ConfigLoader.scala:40)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalDependencies.<init>(PrismaLocalDependencies.scala:48)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain$.delayedEndpoint$com$prisma$local$PrismaLocalMain$1(PrismaLocalMain.scala:13)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain$delayedInit$body.apply(PrismaLocalMain.scala:8)
        at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
        at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:34)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
        at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:76)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:388)
        at scala.App.main(App.scala:76)
        at scala.App.main$(App.scala:74)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain$.main(PrismaLocalMain.scala:8)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain.main(PrismaLocalMain.scala) Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load Prisma config: com.prisma.config.InvalidConfiguration: Expected host to be non-empty
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:26)
        at com.prisma.config.ConfigLoader$.load(ConfigLoader.scala:40)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalDependencies.<init>(PrismaLocalDependencies.scala:48)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain$.delayedEndpoint$com$prisma$local$PrismaLocalMain$1(PrismaLocalMain.scala:13)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain$delayedInit$body.apply(PrismaLocalMain.scala:8)
        at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
        at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:34)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
        at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:76)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:388)
        at scala.App.main(App.scala:76)
        at scala.App.main$(App.scala:74)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain$.main(PrismaLocalMain.scala:8)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain.main(PrismaLocalMain.scala) Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load Prisma config: com.prisma.config.InvalidConfiguration: Expected host to be non-empty
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:26)
        at com.prisma.config.ConfigLoader$.load(ConfigLoader.scala:40)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalDependencies.<init>(PrismaLocalDependencies.scala:48)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain$.delayedEndpoint$com$prisma$local$PrismaLocalMain$1(PrismaLocalMain.scala:13)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain$delayedInit$body.apply(PrismaLocalMain.scala:8)
        at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
        at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:34)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
        at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:76)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:388)
        at scala.App.main(App.scala:76)
        at scala.App.main$(App.scala:74)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain$.main(PrismaLocalMain.scala:8)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain.main(PrismaLocalMain.scala) Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load Prisma config: com.prisma.config.InvalidConfiguration: Expected host to be non-empty
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:26)
        at com.prisma.config.ConfigLoader$.load(ConfigLoader.scala:40)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalDependencies.<init>(PrismaLocalDependencies.scala:48)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain$.delayedEndpoint$com$prisma$local$PrismaLocalMain$1(PrismaLocalMain.scala:13)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain$delayedInit$body.apply(PrismaLocalMain.scala:8)
        at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
        at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:34)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
        at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:76)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:388)
        at scala.App.main(App.scala:76)
        at scala.App.main$(App.scala:74)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain$.main(PrismaLocalMain.scala:8)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain.main(PrismaLocalMain.scala) Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load Prisma config: com.prisma.config.InvalidConfiguration: Expected host to be non-empty
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:26)
        at com.prisma.config.ConfigLoader$.load(ConfigLoader.scala:40)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalDependencies.<init>(PrismaLocalDependencies.scala:48)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain$.delayedEndpoint$com$prisma$local$PrismaLocalMain$1(PrismaLocalMain.scala:13)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain$delayedInit$body.apply(PrismaLocalMain.scala:8)
        at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
        at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:34)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
        at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:76)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:388)
        at scala.App.main(App.scala:76)
        at scala.App.main$(App.scala:74)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain$.main(PrismaLocalMain.scala:8)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain.main(PrismaLocalMain.scala) Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load Prisma config: com.prisma.config.InvalidConfiguration: Expected host to be non-empty
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:26)
        at com.prisma.config.ConfigLoader$.load(ConfigLoader.scala:40)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalDependencies.<init>(PrismaLocalDependencies.scala:48)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain$.delayedEndpoint$com$prisma$local$PrismaLocalMain$1(PrismaLocalMain.scala:13)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain$delayedInit$body.apply(PrismaLocalMain.scala:8)
        at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
        at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:34)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
        at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:76)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:388)
        at scala.App.main(App.scala:76)
        at scala.App.main$(App.scala:74)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain$.main(PrismaLocalMain.scala:8)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain.main(PrismaLocalMain.scala) Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load Prisma config: com.prisma.config.InvalidConfiguration: Expected host to be non-empty
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:26)
        at com.prisma.config.ConfigLoader$.load(ConfigLoader.scala:40)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalDependencies.<init>(PrismaLocalDependencies.scala:48)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain$.delayedEndpoint$com$prisma$local$PrismaLocalMain$1(PrismaLocalMain.scala:13)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain$delayedInit$body.apply(PrismaLocalMain.scala:8)
        at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
        at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:34)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
        at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:76)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:388)
        at scala.App.main(App.scala:76)
        at scala.App.main$(App.scala:74)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain$.main(PrismaLocalMain.scala:8)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain.main(PrismaLocalMain.scala) Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load Prisma config: com.prisma.config.InvalidConfiguration: Expected host to be non-empty
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:26)
        at com.prisma.config.ConfigLoader$.load(ConfigLoader.scala:40)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalDependencies.<init>(PrismaLocalDependencies.scala:48)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain$.delayedEndpoint$com$prisma$local$PrismaLocalMain$1(PrismaLocalMain.scala:13)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain$delayedInit$body.apply(PrismaLocalMain.scala:8)
        at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
        at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:34)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
        at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:76)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:388)
        at scala.App.main(App.scala:76)
        at scala.App.main$(App.scala:74)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain$.main(PrismaLocalMain.scala:8)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain.main(PrismaLocalMain.scala) Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load Prisma config: com.prisma.config.InvalidConfiguration: Expected host to be non-empty
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:26)
        at com.prisma.config.ConfigLoader$.load(ConfigLoader.scala:40)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalDependencies.<init>(PrismaLocalDependencies.scala:48)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain$.delayedEndpoint$com$prisma$local$PrismaLocalMain$1(PrismaLocalMain.scala:13)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain$delayedInit$body.apply(PrismaLocalMain.scala:8)
        at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
        at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:34)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
        at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:76)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:388)
        at scala.App.main(App.scala:76)
        at scala.App.main$(App.scala:74)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain$.main(PrismaLocalMain.scala:8)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain.main(PrismaLocalMain.scala) Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load Prisma config: com.prisma.config.InvalidConfiguration: Expected host to be non-empty
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:26)
        at com.prisma.config.ConfigLoader$.load(ConfigLoader.scala:40)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalDependencies.<init>(PrismaLocalDependencies.scala:48)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain$.delayedEndpoint$com$prisma$local$PrismaLocalMain$1(PrismaLocalMain.scala:13)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain$delayedInit$body.apply(PrismaLocalMain.scala:8)
        at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
        at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:34)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
        at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:76)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:388)
        at scala.App.main(App.scala:76)
        at scala.App.main$(App.scala:74)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain$.main(PrismaLocalMain.scala:8)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain.main(PrismaLocalMain.scala) Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load Prisma config: com.prisma.config.InvalidConfiguration: Expected host to be non-empty
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:26)
        at com.prisma.config.ConfigLoader$.load(ConfigLoader.scala:40)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalDependencies.<init>(PrismaLocalDependencies.scala:48)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain$.delayedEndpoint$com$prisma$local$PrismaLocalMain$1(PrismaLocalMain.scala:13)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain$delayedInit$body.apply(PrismaLocalMain.scala:8)
        at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
        at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:34)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
        at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:76)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:388)
        at scala.App.main(App.scala:76)
        at scala.App.main$(App.scala:74)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain$.main(PrismaLocalMain.scala:8)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain.main(PrismaLocalMain.scala) Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load Prisma config: com.prisma.config.InvalidConfiguration: Expected host to be non-empty
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:26)
        at com.prisma.config.ConfigLoader$.load(ConfigLoader.scala:40)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalDependencies.<init>(PrismaLocalDependencies.scala:48)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain$.delayedEndpoint$com$prisma$local$PrismaLocalMain$1(PrismaLocalMain.scala:13)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain$delayedInit$body.apply(PrismaLocalMain.scala:8)
        at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
        at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:34)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
        at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:76)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:388)
        at scala.App.main(App.scala:76)
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  prisma:
    image: prismagraphql/prisma:1.34
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "4466:4466"
    environment:
      PRISMA_CONFIG: |
        port: 4466
        # uncomment the next line and provide the env var PRISMA_MANAGEMENT_API_SECRET=my-secret to activate cluster security
        # managementApiSecret: my-secret
        databases:
          default:
            connector: mongo
            schema: sample_weatherdata
            uri: >-
              mongodb+srv://admin:admin@demonic-one-sdk7x.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

prisma.yml

```
endpoint: http://localhost:4466
datamodel: datamodel.prisma
databaseType: document

generate:
  - generator: javascript-client
    output: ./generated/prisma-client/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solves the error you had. I cannot connect to your MongoDB instance for a full test, but at least it fixes your issue.

```
version: '3'
services:
  prisma:
    image: prismagraphql/prisma:1.34
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "4466:4466"
    environment:
      PRISMA_CONFIG: |
        port: 4466
        # uncomment the next line and provide the env var PRISMA_MANAGEMENT_API_SECRET=my-secret to activate cluster security
        # managementApiSecret: my-secret
        databases:
          default:
            connector: mongo
            host: demonic-one-sdk7x.mongodb.net
            user: admin
            password: admin
            uri: >-
              mongodb+srv://admin:admin@demonic-one-sdk7x.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Comment: That looks good when this is working. But I can't get it running on my localhost. I have no access restictions. Some idea what is wrong with my default connector? `default:
            connector: mongo
            host: localhost:27017
            uri: >-
              mongodb+srv://@localhost:27017/dbname?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

Comment: do you get an error? where are you trying to use this connector?

Comment: I opened a issue on this. Have a look here for more details please. Thank you. https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/4922